# how to delete a file in php from a directory

Tags: php, windows

I am logged into Windows with an administrator account.

I used the `unlink($filename)` function to delete a file using php but it gives me the following error:

> Warning: unlink(C:/wamp/www/jedda/wp-content/uploads/) [function.unlink]: Permission denied in C:\wamp\www\Jedda\wp-content\plugins\course management\course_file.php on line 242

So how can I delete the file using php?

Comment: You need to ensure that you have the right permissions for both the directory and the file to be able to delete it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the error :

```
unlink(C:/wamp/www/jedda/wp-content/uploads/)
```

**You are trying to delete the folder "uploads"** , not the file . `Unlink` can delete files only NOT folder . Make sure your argument to [unlink()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php) is a valid file .

Answer (score 1):

You do not have permission to delete this file, this file can not be deleted.You can try to modify file permissions.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete a directory you have to use **rmdir** command. And the specific directory has to be empty. You can use a function like **scandir** first to list the files and directories of the specific directory and delete the files with **unlink**.

Answer (score 0):

Use this PHP script:-

```
<?php
    function rmdirr($dirname)
    {
        // Sanity check
        if (!file_exists($dirname)) {
            return false;
        }

        // Simple delete for a file
        if (is_file($dirname)) {
            return unlink($dirname);
        }

        // Loop through the folder
        $dir = dir($dirname);
        while (false !== $entry = $dir->read()) {
            // Skip pointers
            if ($entry == '.' || $entry == '..') {
                continue;
            }

            // Recurse
            rmdirr("$dirname/$entry");
        }

        // Clean up
        $dir->close();
        return rmdir($dirname);
    }
?>
```

This script is to delete a file or a folder.... both